# Why is $\delta\mathbf{u}\cdot \mathrm{div}(\mathbf{\sigma}) = -\mathrm{grad}(\delta\mathbf{u}) \mathbf{:} \mathbf{\sigma}$?

Tags: vector-analysis, tensors

Context is from [this deal.ii tutorial](https://dealii.org/9.2.0/doxygen/deal.II/step_44.html). Screenshot of the relevant part is below.

[image: Context]

I don't get the transformation from $\delta\mathbf{u}\cdot \mathrm{div}(\mathbf{\sigma})$ to $-\mathrm{grad}(\delta\mathbf{u}) \mathbf{:} \mathbf{\sigma}$, that seems to be happening as a part of the first line. $\mathbf{u}$ is the displacement field (vector field), $\sigma$ is the stress tensor (tensor field) and $\delta$ is the variational operator. When I try to break the problem down in index notation, I get

$$\delta\mathbf{u}\cdot \mathrm{div}(\mathbf{\sigma}) = \delta u_i\cdot\frac{\partial\sigma_{ij}}{\partial x_j}$$
and
$$-\mathrm{grad}(\delta\mathbf{u}) \mathbf{:} \mathbf{\sigma} = -\delta\left(\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}\right)\cdot \sigma_{ij}.$$
Which means that $$\delta u_i\cdot\frac{\partial\sigma_{ij}}{\partial x_j} = -\delta\left(\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}\right)\cdot \sigma_{ij}.$$

Can these two terms possibly be the same? There's a minus sign on one of them and not on the other, and in the left side the derivation is taken of $\sigma$ while on the right side it's taken of $u$. I can't see any transformations that would turn one into the other, and I also can't find a mistake in my chain of reasoning, what am I missing here?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly $\delta\mathbf{u}$ means here but the identity is essentially some kind of Green Theorem for variations. $\delta\mathbf{u}\cdot \mathrm{div}(\mathbf{\sigma}) = -\mathrm{grad}(\delta\mathbf{u}) \mathbf{:} \mathbf{\sigma}$ does not hold but note that the first line has the integrals and one extra term. The identity holds when taken together.

Comment: @Korf $\delta\mathbf{u}$ is some kind of virtual displacement field that is used to solve the FEM system later. It's a helpful tip that only the whole system might hold. So far I didn't pay any attention to the right most term in the first line, but clearly it doesn't appear on the left side so there has to be something to it. Could be the result of some Gauss theorem so everything would check out, I'll have a look at that.

Comment: I messed up a bit, it is just a usual Green Theorem for the first term. It does not have anything to do with the variational part. It should be enough to find a suitable formulation of the theorem, $t$ should be a prescribed traction on the boundary or something like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty much just a Green Theorem of the form
$$
\int_\Omega g_i \frac{\partial f_{ij}}{\partial x_j} dV= - \int_\Omega \frac{\partial g_i}{\partial x_j} f_{ij} dV+ \int_{\partial \Omega} g_i f_{ij} n_j dS
$$
where $n$ is the normal to the surface, applied on the term $\int_\Omega \delta\mathbf{u}\cdot \mathrm{div}(\mathbf{\sigma}) d v $.
The term $\sigma_{ij}n_j$ is then written out as $t$ which should be a force prescribed on the boundary.

Answer (score 2):

The author is doing two things at once: integration by parts and invoking the divergence theorem. In coordinate form you have $\delta u \cdot \operatorname{div}\sigma$ being
$\delta u_i\, \partial\sigma_{ij}/\partial x_j$, and
\begin{align}
\delta u_i\, \frac{\partial\sigma_{ij}}{\partial x_j} &=
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\left(\delta u_i\,\sigma_{ij}\right) - 
\frac{\partial \delta u_i}{\partial x_j}\sigma_{ij}.
\end{align}
The second term on the right appears within the integral over $\Omega$ and the first, after using the divergence theorem, in the integral over $\partial\Omega$.